What additional implementation details would this patent application need in order to pass?
1) User A sends a message to User B.
2) If User B does not open the message, then nothing happens after that.
3) If User B does open the message, then User A pays the app an amount in dollars.


As specified above, would this be enough to obtain a patent for the payment system of a messaging app?
If not, could you add the implementation details you think it would need to pass?

EDITED:
let's assume for simplicity sake that this is a novel invention.

Most likely such thin recitations would run into abstract idea problems. But before even getting there, what statutory class would this be in? For example, is it a machine or a process? If a process, is the process being carried out by A, B, or some intermediary party? For 2) how can we be sure that B doesn't open the message (eventually), and how would the "nothing happens after that" be implemented? I'd say it's best to cut 2) and make 3) something like "in response to user B opening the message for the first time, ...". But it would still be very far from passing abstract idea.
